How do I correctly use firebase as a signaling server of WEBRTC mobile?
I am building a mobile video call type of application, and the issue is in the signaling I get various errors when initiating the call also the way to connect all the screens seems like the server is not picked up or working properly.
Here's the codes I tried and pretty much failed.
In  these screens I am initiating call using webrtc and firestore as a signaling server one of the error I am getting is:
1)ERROR  Error initializing call: [TypeError: _n6.indexOf is not a function (it is undefined)]
CalllServer.js
import { RTCSessionDescription, RTCPeerConnection,RTCIceCandidate } from 'react-native-webrtc';
import { db, auth } from "../firebase";
    iceServers: [
      {
        urls: ['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'],
      },
    ],
    iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
  };

  const createOffer = async (pc, receiverId) => {
    const callDoc = db.collection('calls').doc(receiverId);
    const offerCandidates = callDoc.collection('offerCandidates');
  
    pc.onicecandidate = event => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        offerCandidates.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
      }
    };
  
    const offerDescription = await pc.createOffer();
    await pc.setLocalDescription(offerDescription);
  
    const offer = {
      sdp: offerDescription.sdp,
      type: offerDescription.type,
    };
  
    await callDoc.set({ offer });
  
    listenForRemoteAnswer(callDoc, pc);
    listenForIceCandidates(callDoc, pc);
  
    return callDoc; // Return callDoc for further use
  };
  
  const answerCall = async (pc, callId) => {
    const callDoc = db.collection('calls').doc(callId);
    const answerCandidates = callDoc.collection('answerCandidates');
    
    const callData = (await callDoc.get()).data();
  
    const offerDescription = callData.offer;
    await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offerDescription));
  
    const answerDescription = await pc.createAnswer();
    await pc.setLocalDescription(answerDescription);
  
    const answer = {
      sdp: answerDescription.sdp,
      type: answerDescription.type,
    };
  
    await callDoc.update({ answer });
  
    pc.onicecandidate = event => {
      if (event.candidate) {
        answerCandidates.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
      }
    };
  
    listenForIceCandidates(callDoc, pc);
  };
  
  const listenForRemoteAnswer = (callDoc, pc) => {
    callDoc.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      if (!pc.currentRemoteDescription && data?.answer) {
        const answerDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer);
        pc.setRemoteDescription(answerDescription);
      }
    });
  };
  
  const listenForIceCandidates = (callDoc, pc) => {
    const offerCandidates = callDoc.collection('offerCandidates');
    offerCandidates.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(change.doc.data());
          pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        }
      });
    });
  
    const answerCandidates = callDoc.collection('answerCandidates');
    answerCandidates.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(change.doc.data());
          pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        }
      });
    });
  };

export { 
    createOffer, answerCall, listenForRemoteAnswer, listenForIceCandidates,
    servers//configuration
}; 

Dialer.js for initiating the call
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { mediaDevices, RTCView, RTCPeerConnection,RTCSessionDescription } from 'react-native-webrtc';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import { DialerStyle } from './DialerStyle';
import { useAuthContext, useThemeContext } from '../../../../contexts/ExportCtxt';
import { configuration,createOffer,listenForRemoteAnswer,listenForIceCandidates } from '../../../../../server/video_call_server/CallServer';
import MapIcon1 from '../../actions/mapIcon1';
import { db } from '../../../../../server/firebase';


export const Dialer = () => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const theme = useThemeContext();
    const { userData } = route.params || {};
    const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);
    const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(null);
    const [muteMic, setMuteMic] = useState(false);
    const [hideCam, setHideCam] = useState(false);
    const [callId, setCallId] = useState(null);
    const peerConnection = useRef(new RTCPeerConnection(configuration));
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    let timeout;

    useEffect(() => {
        const startLocalStream = async () => {
            const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
            setLocalStream(stream);
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                peerConnection.current.addTrack(track, stream);
            });
        };
    
        const initializeCall = async () => {
            const currentId = userData.receiverId || userData.senderId
            try {
              await startLocalStream();
              const callId = await createOffer(peerConnection.current, currentId); // Get callId here
              console.log("Call ID:", callId);
              setCallId(callId.id); // Store callId in state
            
              // Listen for changes in the call document
              const callDocRef = db.collection('calls').doc(callId);
              callDocRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.data();
                if (data) {
                  if (data.offer) {
                    // Process the offer data here
                    const answerDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data.offer);
                    peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(answerDescription);
                    console.log("Offer data:", data.offer);
                  } else {
                    console.log("No offer data available yet");
                  }
                } else {
                  console.log("Call document not found");
                }
              });
            
              // Listen for remote answer and ICE candidates
              //listenForRemoteAnswer(callId, peerConnection.current);
              listenForIceCandidates(callDocRef, peerConnection.current);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error initializing call:", error);
            }
          };
          
    
        initializeCall();
    
        return () => {
            if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (localStream) localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            if (remoteStream) remoteStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            peerConnection.current.close();
        };
    }, []);

    const handleMuteMic = () => {
        const audioTrack = localStream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        audioTrack.enabled = !audioTrack.enabled;
        setMuteMic(!audioTrack.enabled);
    };

    const handleHideCam = () => {
        const videoTrack = localStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        videoTrack.enabled = !videoTrack.enabled;
        setHideCam(!videoTrack.enabled);
    };

    const handleEndCall = () => {
        if (localStream) localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        if (remoteStream) remoteStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        peerConnection.current.close();
        setCallId(null);
        navigation.goBack();
    };

    return (
        <View style={[DialerStyle.mainContainer, { backgroundColor: theme.videochat.backgroundColor }]}>
            <View style={DialerStyle.overAllContainer}>
                <View style={DialerStyle.streamContainer}>
                    {hideCam ? (
                        <View style={DialerStyle.mainContainer}>
                            <Text style={[DialerStyle.hiddingCam, { color: theme.videochat.name }]}>
                                Camera hidden
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            {localStream && (
                                <RTCView streamURL={localStream.toURL()} style={DialerStyle.localStream} />
                            )}
                            {remoteStream && (
                                <RTCView streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()} style={DialerStyle.remoteStream} />
                            )}
                        </>
                    )}
                </View>
                <MapIcon1
                    handleMuteMic={handleMuteMic}
                    handleHideCam={handleHideCam}
                    handleEndCall={handleEndCall}
                    muteMic={muteMic}
                    hideCam={hideCam}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default function MapIcon1({ handleMuteMic, handleHideCam, handleEndCall, muteMic, hideCam }) {
    const theme = useThemeContext();

    return (
        <View style={[DialerStyle.iconContainer, { backgroundColor: theme.videochat.iconContainer }]}>
            <View style={[DialerStyle.singleIconContainer, { backgroundColor: theme.videochat.innerIconContainer }]}>
                <ActionsIonicon
                    name={muteMic ? "volume-mute" : "volume-high"}
                    size={34}
                    style={DialerStyle.singleIcon}
                    color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
                    route={handleMuteMic}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={[DialerStyle.singleIconContainer, { backgroundColor: theme.videochat.innerIconContainer }]}>
                <ActionsMat
                    name={"phone-hangup"}
                    size={34}
                    style={DialerStyle.singleIcon}
                    color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
                    route={handleEndCall}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={[DialerStyle.singleIconContainer, { backgroundColor: theme.videochat.innerIconContainer }]}>
                <ActionsMat
                    name={hideCam ? "camera-off" : "camera"}
                    size={34}
                    style={DialerStyle.singleIcon}
                    color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
                    route={handleHideCam}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
ReceiveCall.js for incoming call
import { View,Text,Image,ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import React,{useState,useRef,useEffect} from 'react';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { useThemeContext } from '../../../../contexts/ExportCtxt';
import { ReceiveCallStyle } from './ReceiveCallStyle';
import MapIcon2 from '../../actions/mapIcon2';
import { db } from '../../../../../server/firebase';
import { configuration,answerCall,listenForIceCandidates } from '../../../../../server/video_call_server/CallServer';
import { RTCPeerConnection, mediaDevices } from 'react-native-webrtc';
import { ScreenNames } from '../../../../../source/utility/ConstentVar';

export const ReceiveCall = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);
    const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(null);
    const [incomingCall, setIncomingCall] = useState(null);
    const theme = useThemeContext();
    const route = useRoute();
    const { userData } = route.params || {};
    const peerConnection = useRef(new RTCPeerConnection(configuration));
 
  let id = userData.senderId || userData.receiverId

  useEffect(() => {
    const startLocalStream = async () => {
        const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
        setLocalStream(stream);
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
            peerConnection.current.addTrack(track, stream);
        });
    };

    startLocalStream();

    peerConnection.current.ontrack = (event) => {
        setRemoteStream(event.streams[0]);
    };

    const callsRef = db.collection('calls').doc(userData.receiverId);
    callsRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      if (data && data.offer && !data.answer) {
        setIncomingCall(data);
      }
    });

    // peerConnection.current.onicecandidate = (event) => {
    //  if (event.candidate) {
    //      db.collection('calls').doc(id).collection('candidates').add(event.candidate.toJSON());
    //  }
    // };

    answerCall(id, peerConnection.current);
    listenForIceCandidates(db.collection('calls').doc(id), peerConnection.current);

    return () => {
        localStream && localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        remoteStream && remoteStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        peerConnection.current.close();
    };
}, []);

const connectToCall = async() => {
    if (incomingCall) {

        await answerCall(peerConnection.current, userData.receiverId);
        //console.log('Navigating to MoreId with:', { type: 'connected', userData: userData });
        navigation.navigate(ScreenNames.MoreId,{
            screen:ScreenNames.connectedVideoCall,
            params:{type:'connected', userData:userData}
        })
    }
}

  return (
    <View style={[ReceiveCallStyle.container, { backgroundColor: theme.videochat.backgroundColor }]}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                <Text style={[ReceiveCallStyle.name, { color: theme.videochat.name }]}>
                    Call From: {userData.senderName || userData.receiverName}
                </Text>
                <Image 
                    source={{ uri: userData.senderProfilePicture || userData.receiverProfilePicture }}  
                    style={ReceiveCallStyle.image}
                />
            </View>
            <MapIcon2 
                handleAcceptCall={connectToCall}
            />
        </View>
  );
};
export default function MapIcon2({handleAcceptCall,handleEndCall,handleMuteMic,handleHideCam}) {
  const theme = useThemeContext()
  const [flipCam,setFlipCam] = useState(false)
  const [muteMic,setMuteMic] = useState(false)
  const [hideCam,setHideCam] = useState(false)
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);

  const navigation = useNavigation()

   // Fetch user media when component mounts
  //  const handleEndCall = () => {
  //   console.log('call ended')
  //  };
  //  const handleAcceptCall = async(callId, peerConnection) => {
  //   console.log('call answered')
  //  };
 
  //  const handleMuteMic = () => {
  //    setMuteMic(currentValue => !currentValue)
  //  };
 
  //  const handleHideCam = () => {
  //    setHideCam(currentValue => !currentValue)
  //  };
   
return (
    <View style={[ReceiveCallStyle.iconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.iconContainer}]}>
        <View style={[ReceiveCallStyle.singleIconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.innerIconContainer}]}>
      <ActionsIonicon
            name={muteMic? "volume-mute":"volume-high"}
            size={34}
            style={ReceiveCallStyle.singleIcon}
            color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
            route={handleMuteMic}
        />
    </View>

    <View style={[ReceiveCallStyle.singleIconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.innerIconContainer}]}>
      <ActionsMat 
          name={"phone"}
          size={34}
          style={ReceiveCallStyle.singleIcon}
          color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
          route={handleAcceptCall}
      />
    </View>

    <View style={[ReceiveCallStyle.singleIconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.innerIconContainer}]}>
      <ActionsMat 
          name={"phone-hangup"}
          size={34}
          style={ReceiveCallStyle.singleIcon}
          color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
          route={handleEndCall}
      />
    </View>

    <View style={[ReceiveCallStyle.singleIconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.innerIconContainer}]}>
      <ActionsMat 
          name={hideCam?"camera-off":"camera"}
          size={34}
          style={ReceiveCallStyle.singleIcon}
          color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
          route={handleHideCam}
      />
    </View>
</View>
)
}
Connected.js for when call is established
import { View, Text, ImageBackground,Image } from 'react-native'
import React, { useRef,useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import {useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { mediaDevices, RTCView, RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription } from 'react-native-webrtc';

import { DialerStyle } from '../make_call/DialerStyle';
import { useAuthContext,useThemeContext,useVideoCallContext } from '../../../../contexts/ExportCtxt'
import MapIcons from '../../actions/mapIcons'
import { db } from '../../../../../server/firebase';

const configuration = { iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }],
iceCandidatePoolSize: 10, };

// export const Connected = () => {
//     const route = useRoute();
//     const theme = useThemeContext()
//     const {selectedImage} = useAuthContext()
//     const { userData } = route.params || {};
    
//   return (
//     <View style={[DialerStyle.mainContainer, {backgroundColor:theme.videochat.backgroundColor}]}>
//          <View style={[DialerStyle.overAllContainer]}>
//          {userData.senderName && userData.senderProfilePicture ?
//              <ImageBackground source={{ uri: selectedImage }} style={DialerStyle.imageBackground}>
//                      <View style={[DialerStyle.userBeingCalledContainer]} >
//                          <Image 
//                              source={{ uri: userData.senderProfilePicture }}  
//                              style={DialerStyle.calleImage}
//                          />
//                      </View>
//                      <MapIcons/>
//              </ImageBackground>
//              :
//              <ImageBackground source={{ uri: selectedImage }} style={DialerStyle.imageBackground}>
//                  <View style={[DialerStyle.userBeingCalledContainer]} >
//                     <Image 
//                       source={{ uri: userData.receiverProfilePicture }}  
//                       style={DialerStyle.calleImage}
//                     />
//                 </View>
//                 <MapIcons/>
//          </ImageBackground>
//          }
//         </View>
//     </View>
//   )
// }

export const Connected = () => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const theme = useThemeContext();
    const { userData } = route.params || {};
    const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);
    const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(null);
    const peerConnection = useRef(new RTCPeerConnection(servers));
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const startLocalStream = async () => {
        const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
        setLocalStream(stream);
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
          peerConnection.current.addTrack(track, stream);
        });
      };
  
      const startCall = async () => {
        await startLocalStream();
  
        peerConnection.current.ontrack = (event) => {
          setRemoteStream(event.streams[0]);
        };
  
        if (userData.senderName) {
          // If the user is the caller, create an offer
          const offer = await peerConnection.current.createOffer();
          await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(offer);
          // Save offer to Firestore and handle signaling here
        } else {
          // If the user is the receiver, set the remote description and create an answer
          const callDoc = db.collection('calls').doc(userData.callId);
          const callData = (await callDoc.get()).data();
  
          const offerDescription = callData.offer;
          await peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offerDescription));
  
          const answerDescription = await peerConnection.current.createAnswer();
          await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(answerDescription);
  
          // Save answer to Firestore and handle signaling here
        }
      };
  
      startCall();
  
      return () => {
        if (localStream) localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        if (remoteStream) remoteStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        peerConnection.current.close();
      };
    }, []);
  
    return (
      <View style={[DialerStyle.mainContainer, { backgroundColor: theme.videochat.backgroundColor }]}>
        <View style={DialerStyle.overAllContainer}>
          {localStream && (
            <RTCView streamURL={localStream.toURL()} style={DialerStyle.imageBackground} />
          )}
          {remoteStream && (
            <RTCView streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()} style={DialerStyle.calleImage} />
          )}
          <MapIcons />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
  
  const servers = {
    iceServers: [
      {
        urls: ['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'],
      },
    ],
    iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
  };

import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

import { ActionsIonicon } from './ActionsIonicon'
import { useThemeContext } from '../../../contexts/ExportCtxt'
import { ActionsMat } from './ActionsMaticon'
import { ConnectedStyle } from '../dialer/connected_call/ConnectedStyle'
import { mediaDevices } from 'react-native-webrtc'

export default function MapIcons() {
  const theme = useThemeContext()
  const [flipCam,setFlipCam] = useState(false)
  const [muteMic,setMuteMic] = useState(false)
  const [hideCam,setHideCam] = useState(false)
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);

  const navigation = useNavigation()

   // Fetch user media when component mounts
   useEffect(() => {
    
  }, []);

  const handleMuteMic = () => {
    setMuteMic(currentValue => !currentValue)
  };

  const handleHideCam = () => {
    setHideCam(currentValue => !currentValue)
  };

  const handleFlipCam = async () => {
    setFlipCam(currentValue => !currentValue)
  };
  const handleEndCall = () => {
    console.log('end call')
  };

 
return (
  <View style={[ConnectedStyle.iconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.iconContainer}]}>
    <View style={[ConnectedStyle.singleIconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.innerIconContainer}]}>
      <ActionsIonicon
            name={muteMic? "volume-mute":"volume-high"}
            size={34}
            style={ConnectedStyle.singleIcon}
            color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
            route={handleMuteMic}
        />
    </View>

    <View style={[ConnectedStyle.singleIconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.innerIconContainer}]}>
      <ActionsIonicon 
          name={"camera-reverse-sharp"}
          size={34}
          style={ConnectedStyle.singleIcon}
          color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
          route={handleFlipCam}
      />
    </View>

    <View style={[ConnectedStyle.singleIconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.innerIconContainer}]}>
      <ActionsMat 
          name={"phone-hangup"}
          size={34}
          style={ConnectedStyle.singleIcon}
          color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
          route={handleEndCall}
      />
    </View>

    <View style={[ConnectedStyle.singleIconContainer,{backgroundColor:theme.videochat.innerIconContainer}]}>
      <ActionsMat 
          name={hideCam?"camera-off":"camera"}
          size={34}
          style={ConnectedStyle.singleIcon}
          color={theme.arrowColor.arrowBackground}
          route={handleHideCam}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
)
}

VideoChat is responsible for displaying screens above
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Dialer } from './dialer/make_call/Dialer';
import { ReceiveCall } from './dialer/receive_call/ReceiveCall';
import { Connected } from './dialer/connected_call/Connected';

export const VideoChat = () => {
  const route = useRoute();
  const { type, userData } = route.params || {};

  return (
    <View>
      {userData? (
        <>
        <Dialer userData={userData} />
        <ReceiveCall userData={userData} />
        <Connected userData={userData} />
        </>
      ): <Text>Users</Text>}

    </View>
  );
};


There is way too much code here for us to efficiently help. While you may always get lucky and somebody may spot the problem and answer, chances of that drastically go up if you take the time to create a minimal repro

Hello, Frank I rebuild it and it work only when document id i.e meetingId is constent or hard coded the issue remain firestore rules can you help out or anyone looking at this? link for the full code down, all I need is a firestore rule that restricts this to only involved users:https://github.com/MVITA-nkanga/video-call-.git
